# simple code doesn't work. Dunno why

Tags: c

Got xCode 5.0.2 bought mac yesterday and do not understand why this simple code doesn't work.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    int N;
    printf("vvedite koli4estvo dannih\n");//mistake and warning is here
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int *arr = new (int [N]);

    return 0;
}
```

mistake is

```
expected expression

implicit declaration of function 'new' is invalid in c99
```

Comment: This is in `main.m` file? Change to `main.mm`

Comment: try this `int arr[N];`

Comment: tried int arr[N] also mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is written in C but you are using `new`; a C++ operator. Use `malloc` instead.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*N); // allocates memory for N itegers
```

Comment: don't you know how I can make my xCode to read c++ as well as c? because on MSDN first code reads well

Comment: Almost all ansi C codes run on c++ compilers.